# D3: Zoom does not reset the scale

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I've got a simple chart with some simulated live data. You can toggle the drawing on and off. When drawing is switched off you can zoom in and out.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wqyz1q3o45

Here is the problem:

1. Wait for some time to have some data on the screen
2. Click on 'toggle' to stop drawing new data
3. Zoom in (mouse wheel or double click) and out
4. Click on 'toggle' to start drawing again

You can see that the line is being eaten up from the left. That's because the scales aren't reset.

Here is the `render` method

```
public render(data: ISample[]) {
  this.xScale.domain(extent(data, d => d.timestamp) as [number, number]);
  this.yScale.domain(extent(data, d => d.value) as [number, number]);

  this.xAxisGroup.call(this.xAxis as any);
  this.yAxisGroup.call(this.yAxis as any);

  this.xGridGroup.call(this.xGrid as any);
  this.yGridGroup.call(this.yGrid as any);

  this.lineGroup.datum(data).attr("d", this.line);
}
```

And the `zoom` method

```
public zoom = () => {
  const newXScale = event.transform.rescaleX(this.xScale);
  const newYScale = event.transform.rescaleY(this.yScale);

  this.xAxisGroup.call(this.xAxis.scale(newXScale));
  this.yAxisGroup.call(this.yAxis.scale(newYScale));

  this.xGridGroup.call(this.xGrid.scale(newXScale));
  this.yGridGroup.call(this.yGrid.scale(newYScale));

  this.line.x(d => newXScale(d.timestamp)).y(d => newYScale(d.value));

  this.lineGroup.attr("d", this.line as any);
};
```

If you use the following code in the `render` method instead or comment/uncomment the appropriate lines it works.

```
this.xAxisGroup.call(this.xAxis.scale(this.xScale));
this.yAxisGroup.call(this.yAxis.scale(this.yScale));

this.xGridGroup.call(this.xGrid.scale(this.xScale));
this.yGridGroup.call(this.yGrid.scale(this.yScale));

this.line.x(d => this.xScale(d.timestamp)).y(d => this.yScale(d.value));
```

You can click on 'toggle' and zoom in/out as much as you want.

Why do I have to reset the scales in the `render` method? Especially something like

```
this.line.x(d => this.xScale(d.timestamp)).y(d => this.yScale(d.value));
```

that never changes. It should always be the same. I thought zooming out again resets the scale back to the initial value.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: you don't update the `line.x()` and `line.y()` after zoom, (line is commented out)

Comment: and for the axis and grids: switch the comments versions: you need to update the scale for the axis after zoom

Answer (score 0):

Change chart.ts render function

```
  public render(data: ISample[]) {
    this.xScale.domain(extent(data, d => d.timestamp) as [number, number]);
    this.yScale.domain(extent(data, d => d.value) as [number, number]);

    // this.xAxisGroup.call(this.xAxis as any);
    this.xAxisGroup.call(this.xAxis.scale(this.xScale));

    // this.yAxisGroup.call(this.yAxis as any);
    this.yAxisGroup.call(this.yAxis.scale(this.yScale));

    // this.xGridGroup.call(this.xGrid as any);
    // this.yGridGroup.call(this.yGrid as any);
    this.xGridGroup.call(this.xGrid.scale(this.xScale));
    this.yGridGroup.call(this.yGrid.scale(this.yScale));

    this.line.x(d => this.xScale(d.timestamp)).y(d => this.yScale(d.value));

    this.lineGroup.datum(data).attr("d", this.line);
  }
```

Comment: but why? I shouldn't be necessary to reset the scale every time. Zooming out should reset the scale. If you don't zoom in/out it all works fine. Your solution is simply the code I've given in the question.

Comment: @zemirco: you change the scale(s) and accessor functions in the zoom handler, you need to set them back